# Testing In App Purchase issues. IAP iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have got one big problem with an IAP purchase testing.

There are next steps which I have made:

1. Create App ID (**com.domainname.appname**)
2. Create Development Provisioning Profile with an App ID (**com.domainname.appname**)
3. Create App on iTunes Connect (Bundle ID **com.domainname.appname**)
4. Manage IAP. Create non-consumable products with Product ID **com.testitem1, com.testitem2, com.testitem3** (there is Ready to Submit status for each products)

**Configurate XCode project settings**

- Bundle identifier: **com.domainname.appname**
- Code Signing Identity: Development Provisioning Profile that I have made on the **step 2**
- Deployment target: 4.0

**Device**

iPod Touch 4gen iOS 5.1.1

**Write source code**

My class support `SKProductsRequestDelegate`

in `- viewDidLoad` callback method I have wrote these lines:

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
{
    NSLog(@"YES, I CAN MAKE PAYMENTS");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NO, I CAN NOT MAKE PAYMENTS"); 
}
```

On this stage everything is okay. I can make payments.

Next, I'm try to create request for my products:

```
SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObjects:@"com.testitem1", @"com.testitem2", @"com.testitem3", nil]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

On this stage everything is okay also and on next stage my request object invoke callback method below:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    NSLog(@"%@", myProduct);
}
```

But there are not any products in response and I can not understand why.

I already have this problem before (i just reset my device and everything worked good), but in this case I can not figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have went through this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

In my case this is was related that I have not got **Banking Information**. If you want to test your IAP you must have an iOS Paid Applications contract (iOS) with a your tax information.

Comment: I have question .When you accept contract ,  they take deposit or no ? Thank you

Comment: @ErhanDemirci what do you mean? ) can you explain about which deposit you have said?

Comment: itunes connect >Contracts, Tax, and Banking >Master Agreements >Bank Info  click to setup

Comment: and follow saying :..Accounts Payable to electronically deposit payments to the designated bank account . what is mean ? When I accept contract , they take deposit or no ?

Comment: @ErhanDemirci as I remember there is no additional payment. Just payment when you sell your apps or purchases. There is a tax on each item that has been bought by user.

Comment: Thank you alexander exactly writing like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/oaZyd.png . Are you thinking same ?

Comment: yes no problem, but honestly if you want to get full information how it works you can create new question where you will ask about it. because my answer is connected to the in app purchases but not to the banking information, tax etc. also you can use apple support to understand which deposit they can take in some case.

Comment: Guys, I need some help. My banking information and tax information is setup correctly, bundle id and product IDs also match but the `productsRequest didreceive` delegate never fires...

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you haven't yet uploaded the app's binary in iTunes Connect. Go to iTunes Connect, upload the app's binary. Once it's uploaded, reject it straight away so that it's marked as "Developer Rejected".

This is a necessary step for you to receive `SKProductResponse` if it's the first version of your app. It won't affect your app's review.

Comment: thanks you, but I still can't get SKProductResponse. I have uploaded binary and reject it.

Comment: also now the status for each pack Waiting for Review

Comment: I have also got another account and I'm test IAP without any problem.

Comment: maybe it's related with Banking Information (I sent request just today)

Comment: Uploading the binary is not a necessary step. I've see this mentioned a lot, yet I have had IAP work on several apps before I've uploaded the binary.

Comment: What happens if you include only `"com.testitem1"` in the NSSet you give to `initWithProductIdentifiers`?

Comment: I have answered on my question. There is an issue with my Bank Information. After I submit it all my products has been displayed.